# Proof-check: Any subset of $1,...,2n$ with order $\geq n+1 $ contains some element which divides another, assuming $n>1$.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I just want to confirm my proof is error free, since it seems quite different from others I've come across.

Consider $\{\sigma,...,2n\}$ for $\sigma \in \{1,...,n\}$. Obviously we have:

$n \mid 2n$ , $n-1 \mid 2n-2$ , . . . , $\sigma \mid 2\sigma$

For all $x,y\in \{\sigma,...,n\}$ we know $2x \ne 2y$ unless $x=y$. Thus if $2x \notin \{\sigma,...,n\}$ then at least one novel member of every such pair $\{x,2x\}$ must be deleted from $\{\sigma,...,2n\}$ to prevent having an entry and its double in $\{\sigma,...,2n\}$. If instead $2x\in \{\sigma,...,n\}$ then we must delete at least two members (at least one novel) of every such triple $\{x,2x,4x\}$ from $\{\sigma,...,2n\}$ to prevent having an entry and its double and / or quadruple in $\{\sigma,...,2n\}$.

This means we must remove at least one novel element $\textit{for}$ each member of $\{\sigma,...,n\}$, which amounts to removing at least $n-\sigma+1$ elements from $\{\sigma,...,2n\}$ thus leaving us with less than $n+1$ elements if we are to have no elements which divide each other.

Comment: What is $\sigma$ supposed to be?  The smallest element?

Comment: @Randall Correct!

Comment: @bof Sorry I've edited the post a few times for clarification so you might give it another read. My idea for the proof was to start with the set containing all members from $\sigma$ to $2n$ and show that we must delete at least $n- \sigma +1$ elements in order to avoid having an element and its double or quadruple be left in the remaining set.

Comment: Anyway, there is a far simpler proof. Take the odd part of each number by factoring out all the $2$s. Since there are only $n$ odd numbers between $1$ and $2n$ inclusive, two of your $n+1$ numbers have the same odd part; and then the one with fewer $2$s in its factorization divides the other one.

Comment: @bof Ok yeah that is definitely simpler than mine. I saw some really complicated proofs online when checking my answer, and I felt there had to be a more straightforward way to address this.

Comment: @bof you should write this up as an answer...very nice

Comment: @Mike Thanks, but the OP is asking us to check **his** proof, so posting a different proof would not be answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

This proof follows a generally bad pattern that can be described as "Let me think of the worst thing that could happen, and then show that it doesn't happen." Such proofs have two perils:

1. You may think of a bad thing, but fail to think of the *worst*, and because the proof doesn't contain a proof that your situation is the worst, no one (especially you) ever notices it.
2. The second-worst thing might also provide a counterexample if you're not careful.

If you want to show that for every subset $S$ of size $n_+1$, some property holds, your proof should almost certainly start with "Let $S = \{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}$ be a subset, where the $x_i$ are all distinct, so that $S$ has $n+1$ elements. We now show that ..."

Saying "Let $S$ be the subset containing the top $n+1$ elements" makes the assumption that this is the "worst case", and you're headed down a very bad path.

Comment: I did not assume anywhere in my proof that $\sigma=n$.

Comment: You're right. Instead you started with an interval  $\{sigma, \ldots, 2n\}$ of the naturals, and observed that a set derived by "deleting at least one one of each pair of doubles" had no more than $n$ elements. But you *didn't* show that every set $S$ that meets the specification has this form. It *does,* of course, and you can show that by starting with $\sigma = 1$, thus getting rid of a lot of junk in your proof, but there's still work to do. I guess the right critique is "I can handle every case of type T" isn't a complete proof until you show that "every case *is* actually of type T".